# Odoo 10 - XMLRPC - Use external XML identifier

Tags: python, odoo, xml-rpc, odoo-10, xmlrpclib

I am creating a new record via XMLRPC.

Specificaly, I want to populate the field `team_id` in `crm.lead`.

I would like to populate that field using `sales_team.salesteam_website_sales` (i.e. **the external XML ID**) instead of the number `2` (i.e. **the regular ID**).

Is that possible using XMLRPC `create`, if so, what shall I use?

Odoo 10 CE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this method of `ir.model.data`:

```
@api.model
def _get_id(self, module, xml_id):
    """Returns the id of the ir.model.data record corresponding to a given module and xml_id (cached) or raise a ValueError if not found"""
    return self.xmlid_lookup("%s.%s" % (module, xml_id))[0]
```

It can be used to replace the functionality of `self.env.ref`.

Call it from XMLRPC (send the module name and the XML ID as parameters), and it will return the ID in database of the record with that XML ID. Store that ID in a variable and use this variable to populate `team_id`.

The XMLRPC code will vary depending on the programming language you're using (Pyhon, PHP, Ruby or Java).

**EDIT**

As **@Naglis** said, the method I suggested you is not going to work, as it's a private method. Use the public one, `xmlid_to_res_id`, to achieve what you need.

Comment: Unfortunately, private model methods (starting with an underscore) cannot be called via XML/JSON RPC. [[1](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/815c2a324dde5dc55c15c46b36c2ec45f653e22c/odoo/models.py#L104-L107)], [[2](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/815c2a324dde5dc55c15c46b36c2ec45f653e22c/odoo/service/model.py#L163)]. Suggest to use [`xmlid_to_res_id`](https://git.io/vxmVD) on `ir.model.data` model.

Comment: I didn't realized that, so @Naglis provided the right answer. Thanks for the info, I'll edit the answer.